# How can i make the table unexpandable? or vertically expansion of the <td> content

Tags: html, css

[SEE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wagca.jpg)

I just want to know what the attributes are for `table` to make it unexpandable? Or vice versa for the `<td>` content? (vertical instead of horizontal)?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading"><b>Implementation/Migration Plan</b></div>
<div class="panel-body">
<table class="table table-condensed">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Activities</th>
<th>Duration</th> 
<th>Responsible</th>
<th>Back-out Procedure</th>
<th>Remarks</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td contenteditable='true'></td>
<td contenteditable='true'></td>
<td contenteditable='true'></td>
<td contenteditable='true'></td>
<td contenteditable='true'></td>
</tr>
```

Currently, I have no table attributes and the whenever I input long string in it, it expands both the `thead` and `tbody` horizontally. I just want to know how to adjust the input size

Comment: You can either fix the width of `tr` content or let it expand vertically which allows `td` in fixed width,
here is a fiddle you can reffer :https://jsfiddle.net/7m1tL4tf/

Answer (score 0):

Use css:

```
<style>
td {
  width: 100px;
  word-break: break-all;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

This will control the text to be expanded vertically (breaking the long string by `word-break`).